# Finding JSON key match with jQuery and PokéAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to find and use an english translation of a language JSON endpoint using the PokéAPI in an app I am developing. I need to utilise translations when submitting a call to one of the urls shown below. Unfortunately, the english language key is not always in the same order in the array response so I need a way of finding and checking for it so that the correct english translation is shown on the front-end.

Im trying to retrieve: 
`flavor_text_entries[X].language.en` key in each search and retrieve the `flavor_text_entries[X].flavor_text` to show the description on the front-end.

API URL 1:

```
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/3/
```

API URL 2:

```
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/10/
```

Code:

```
var pokeBio = $("[data-poke-bio]").html();

function submit(){

 var pokeID = $("[data-poke-id]").val();
 var pokeSpecURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/" + pokeID;

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: pokeSpecURL,
    success: function(dataSpec){ 
      ajaxSpecSuccess(dataSpec);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      ajaxError();
    }
  });
}

function ajaxSpecSuccess(dataSpec){
  var pokeMatchBio = dataSpec.flavor_text_entries[1].flavor_text;
  var pokeBio = $("[data-poke-bio]").html(pokeMatchBio);
}
```

Snippet I need to manipulate:

```
var pokeMatchBio = dataSpec.flavor_text_entries[1].flavor_text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1, find the english entry

Step 2, display its flavor_text or a message if it wasn't found

```
let englishEntry = dataSpec.flavor_text_entries.find(entry => entry.language && entry.language.name && entry.language.name === 'en');

if (englishEntry) {
  console.log(englishEntry.flavor_text);
} else {
  console.log("English entry not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was after!